# Как используя переменные и/или цикл, либо другие возможности, реализовать поочередную авторизацию при Number of Threads (users) = 10

Tags: jmeter

Я использую набор логинов "username" см.скрин-1 (admin1 - admin11) с одинаковыми паролями и Number of Threads users = 10.
[image: скрин-1]
Сейчас я смог реализовать работу с разной авторизацией путем выбора рандомного значения см.скрин-2[image: скрин-2] из массива и записи его в переменную которая используется при авторизации в HTTP Authorization Manager, но рандомные значения могут повторятся, поэтому я пытаюсь реализовать метод поочередной авторизации admin1, потом admin2...admin11. Цикл не помог, всегда берется последнее значение на котором он закончился, как я могу реализовать последовательную авторизацию (по возможности на js)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто используйте функцию [${__threadNum}](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) прямо в теле запроса

```
admin${__threadNum}
```

для первого пользователя значение будет `admin1`, для второго `admin2`, и т.д.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На будущее, не используйте JavaScript, каждый раз ваш код будет интерпретироваться движком [Nashorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_(JavaScript_engine)) и при больших нагрузках именно выполнение JavaScript будет "узким местом", если вдруг придется писать код - пишите на [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел еще один простой способ решения вопроса, это использование обычного Counter, он так же помогает решить вопрос авторизации
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]